# Creation of an IF formula that will return a 1 or 0 for times between a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to create a spreadsheet that will calculate total number of patients per hour. I have an arrival time and a discharge time. What I was thinking is to organize my spreadsheet with times on a 24 hour clock and return a 1 or 0 if conditions are met. So for example in cell A2(my arrival time) I have a time of 00:10. In cell B2 I have a discharge time of 01:23. My top row is the header row and I have 0:00 in C1, 1:00 in C2, 2:00 in C3, etc. (a time continuum across to Z1 for 23:00). My goal would be to create a formula that would a 1 value in the 0:00 column (because they arrived at 00:10), a 1 value in the 1:00 column, but a 0 value in the 2:00 column because they have been discharged. My brain is spent on trying to figure this out! :)

Comment: Some diagrams of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: What about patients that are admitted to ER or spend multiple days? Have you thought about using decimals as well? 0.1 is 6 minutes. If you look A4/B4 of Gary's example, you see they have 3 1s even though their total time was really only 90 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

In **C2** enter:

```
=OR(AND(C$1<$A2,$A2<D$1),AND(C$1<$B2,$B2<D$1),AND($A2<C$1,$B2>D$1))*1
```

and copy both across and down:

[image]

For example, the **C2** case covers three sub-cases for **1**:

- the start time is greater than **C1** and less than **D1**
- the end time is greater than **C1** and less than **D1**
- the start time is less than **C1** and the end time is greater than **D1**

Also use **<=** where appropriate.

Comment: You are brilliant! Thank you so much. I killed a lot of brain cells trying to figure out that formula. :)